# How to delete same elements in different tuples

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary like this and want to remove elements if the first item has already occurred in the tuple.

Original dictionary:

```
{85: [(88, 1), (89, 2), (89, 3), (89, 4)], 
86: [(77, 1)], 
112: [(35, 1), (36, 2)], 
114: [(55, 1), (55, 2), (55, 3), (55, 4), (55, 5), (55, 6), (55, 7), (55, 8), (55, 9), (55, 10), (55, 11), (55, 12), (55, 13), (55, 14), (55, 15), (55, 16), (55, 17), (55, 18), (55, 19), (55, 20)], 
122: [(72, 1), (72, 2), (72, 3), (72, 4), (72, 5), (72, 6), (72, 7), (72, 8)]}
```

Target:

```
{85: [(88, 1), (89, 2)], 
86: [(77, 1)],
112: [(35, 1), (36, 2)], 
114: [(55, 1)], 
122: [(72, 1)]}
```

Comment: So, the idea is that you want to process each list separately? Then the fact that they're inside the dictionary is not really relevant - just write the code that can process one list, and then iterate over the `.values()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this solution is not the efficent one but it is short. The idea is to iterate each list backward and put it in dict so if some keys are the same it leaves only the last ones.

```
target = {k: list(dict(v[::-1]).items())[::-1] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: This is perhaps a bit too clever - it's not only abusing the fact that the current implementation of `dict`s maintains order,  but the fact that the list elements are 2-tuples that a `dict` can be constructed from. On the other hand, the fact that the data looks like that, combined with the fact that the OP wants to deduplicate in this specific way, suggests that maybe the data should have been `dict`s in the first place :)